# How to remove duplicate mail ids in a text file and make a unique file and update it with reponded mails so to remind the non-repondents

Tags: email, sorting, duplicates

My problem is 
I have a set of over 150 email ids with duplicates. They are in .txt file with comma seperated continuous lines.

Example: the list might be like this

```
abc@m.com, cvb@m.com, abc@m.com, ert@m.com, fdb@m.com, cvb@m.com
```

Now i want to make them as one email id per line

```
abc@m.com, 
cvb@m.com
abc@m.com
ert@m.com
fdb@m.com
cvb@m.com
```

Then i want to make it as unique list by removing the mail ids

```
abc@m.com
ert@m.com
fdb@m.com
cvb@m.com
```

and two duplicates i.e. abc@m.com and cvb@m.com are removed

Then i want to update the list by removing the email ids who responded to my mail and send a reminder to the remaining people 
i.e. let us say that

```
ert@m.com
```

replied to my mail and the task is done and now after 10 days i want to remind again the rest of the people i.e. a reminder to nonrepondent where i am creating a text file of responded contacts. and i have obtain a list which consists of only non respondents by differing both all contacts and respondent contacts which looks like below

```
abc@m.com
fdb@m.com
cvb@m.com
```

All this i have to do with more than 200 mail ids so i need scipting help for this.Can any one help me out?? Your help is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use some Linux (or Mac OS X, or cygwin) shell, translate all `,` combinations to newlines and sort and filter them.

```
tr ", " "\n" <addresses.txt |sort |uniq
```

Which will output

```
abc@m.com
cvb@m.com
ert@m.com
fdb@m.com
```